# JAVA Method returns unexpected value

Tags: java

I am a very new java programmer, the below code is my first attempt at my own project.  I'm certain the code is a mess, please forgive me.

In the below code the user is prompted to enter 5 values between 1 and 50.
I am placing the input values into an int[].
I want to verify that the numbers are in range so I pass the value to a method.
MY ISSUE:
If the value is in range it gets returned then the for loop increments to repeat - Good Behavior
If an invalid value is entered the check is done, error message is displayed and the user is prompted to reenter a proper value.
If one invalid entry is made and a proper value is entered on the second attempt, a correct value is returned - Good Behavior
If two invalid entries are made the second invalid entry somehow gets passed back to the for loop and gets added to array - BAD Behavior

I am certain there is something simple I am missing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("you get 5 elements between 01 & 50:");
    int a[] = new int[5];
    System.out.println("\nEnter all the elements:");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5;)
    {
        int b = in.nextInt();
        a[i] = checkNum(b);
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("Numbers:" + Arrays.toString(a));
    in.close();
}

static int checkNum(int z) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (z>0 && z<51) {
        return z;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry!! Enter a valid number between 01 & 50");
        int qz = s.nextInt();
        z = qz;
        checkNum(qz);
    }
    return z;
}
```

Comment: I think you just need to add `return checkNum(qz);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resides in your `checkNum()`, you are using recursion here, I don't think you know this (if you do that's great).

You need to `return` the checkNum(qz) value, I have simplified your logic a bit.

```
static int checkNum(int z) {
    if (z<1 || z>50) // check for false value 
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry!! Enter a valid number between 01 & 50");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        return checkNum(s.nextInt());
    }
    return z;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Your solution worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow a simpler approach assuming the user will input numbers and not other characters (that would throw an exception),

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("you get 5 elements between 01 & 50:");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a[] = new int[5];

        int i = 0;
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter an element:");
            int b = in.nextInt();

            if (b > 0 && b < 51){
                a[i] = b;
                i++;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry!! Enter a valid number between 01 & 50");
            }
        }while(i < 5);

        in.close();
        System.out.println("Numbers:" + Arrays.toString(a));
    }
```

Here you're asking for valid input until the threshold of 5 is reached. Because you don't know beforehand how many times the user will provide input, until the criteria are met, a `do-while` loop is used.